Need help to center Button in CSS
I'm struggling making the download button right. I want it to be in center. But every time I end up having it at odd positions.


.PDF-Download {
  display: block;
  border-color: rgb(218, 251, 3);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(204, 192, 28);
}
<p class="PDF-Download">Download PDF Summary</p>





Can you add your html and css code please?

i made an edit on my question, check it out now :3

No proper HTML provided. There are tons of example on how to center on net.

ok Mr u know it better.... i tried them all and end up with my button being not in the middle at all.... i tried at least 3-4 solutions... else i wouldnt ask here

a paregraph is not a button and should never be used as such. but the following CSS will help: display. inline-block; margin: 0 auto;

Ok ur right. but for test purpose it would still be ok right?
So u advise me to use an anchor?

@seyoIV: What specifically is "not right" about it?  Do you just want it to not be the full width of the container?  Something else?

I think he needs it so the 'button' doesn't take the whole width of the screen right?

well u see the left pic.. its the challenge for me to rebuild it. But my pseudo button has too much space between the TEXT and the outer border



.PDF-Download {
  display: block;
  border-color: rgb(218, 251, 3);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(204, 192, 28);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
<button class="PDF-Download">Download PDF Summary</button>




You need to use a Button tag
You need to use margin 0 auto in this case


Ok so i had 2 mistakes. Button instead of p and margin. Thank you :D!!
Sry for my noobness but im still learnign since 10 days. ^^

u are welcome my friend. actually u need to learn Flex or Grid in the future.
